# Update MANY GUI elements from background thread

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I use in my program a background worker and I want to update many elements or access many elements form the GUI thread. (like labels text, richtextbox text, etc.) IN a word many.

I know I have to use Invoke like in the following:

```
 Private Sub ClearListViewItems(ByVal [Listview] As ListView)

    If [Listview].InvokeRequired Then
        Dim myDelegate As New ListViewClearItemsDelegate(AddressOf ClearListViewItems)
        Me.Invoke(myDelegate, New Object() {[Listview]})
    Else
        [Listview].Items.Clear()
    End If
End Sub
```

It is not so convenient to write so many functions to have access to my GUI elements.

Is there a more efficient way to handle this?
Or maybe shorter way?

Thank you

Comment: Just write all the actions that you need to perform in a single function and then pass that function to `Invoke()`. What could be simpler?

Comment: i have to access the items separately, in different  moments...

Comment: Maybe this: https://www.codeproject.com/Messages/5086195/Informative-but-out-dated.aspx  ?

Comment: The link provided above by @VisualVincent should do the trick for you. That extension method will reduce the number of lines of code you need to write if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes.. thank you...